# Delegated event doesn't work for elements after sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, events

I have this HTML element:

```
<div class="row preview-pictogram">
  <div class="column3 col-xs-3" data-index="3">
    <span class="index">Spalte <span>3</span></span>
    <span class="dec p-2">-</span>
    <span class="width">3</span>
    <span class="inc p-2">+</span>
  </div>
  <div class="column1 col-xs-4" data-index="1">
    <span class="index">Spalte <span>1</span></span>
    <span class="dec p-2">-</span>
    <span class="width">4</span>
    <span class="inc p-2">+</span>
  </div>
  <div class="column4 col-xs-3" data-index="4">
    <span class="index">Spalte <span>4</span></span>
    <span class="dec p-2">-</span>
    <span class="width">3</span>
    <span class="inc p-2">+</span>
  </div>
  <div class="column2 col-xs-3" data-index="2">
    <span class="index">Spalte <span>2</span></span>
    <span class="dec p-2">-</span>
    <span class="width">3</span>
    <span class="inc p-2">+</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The is a (delegated) event that listens on the click event of the `.dec` and `.inc` classes:

```
$(".dec, .inc").on("click", this.overlay, function () {
  _this.updateWidth(this);
});
```

This works fine. But at one point I'm sorting the columns by its class name with this code:

```
ColumnConfigurator.prototype.sortColumns = function (columns) {
  var items = $("div", columns).get();
  items.sort(sort_by_class);
  $(columns).html(items);
};

var sort_by_class = function(a, b) {
  return $(a).attr("class").localeCompare($(b).attr("class"));
};
```

After that happened that delegated event from above doesn't work anymore. I wonder why that happens. I thought the point of delegated events is that they work also for new elements. `this.overlay` is an element that contains the HTML above and it doesn't change at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.on() should be used on the parent.
In your case if this.overlay is a jQuery element that contains the posted HTML then

```
this.overlay.on("click", ".dec, .inc", function () {
  _this.updateWidth(this);
});
```

Comment: Oh boy, now I'm embarrassed. How blind can you get when you're lost in you're code... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

After checking @noriMonsta answer I realized that I wrote a wrong code.
I update my answer but I give him all the credit.

---

> I thought the point of delegated events is that they work also for new elements.

Yes, but you are not delegating the events, but attaching them directly to the target elements.

```
$("div span").on("click", ".dev, .inc", function () {
  _this.updateWidth(this);
});
```

In the code above you are delegating the event to the div elements. As long as the divs exist all the time, your events will trigger even if you alter their inner HTML.

Cleaner, as noriMonsta wrote:

```
this.overlay.on("click", ".dec, .inc", function () {
  _this.updateWidth(this);
});
```

Because, as you said, `this.overlay` is an element whose content doens't change never.

In the following snippet you can check how undelegated (or direct) events stop to work after the DOM manipulation:

```js
$(".dec, .inc").on("click", function() {
  $("#results").append("not delegated<br>");
});
$(".column").on("click", ".dec, .inc", function() {
  $("#results").append("delegated<br>");
});
$("#alterDOM").on("click", function() {
  $(".column").html( $(".column").html() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <span class="dec">dec</span>
    <span class="inc">inc</span>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <span class="dec">dec</span>
    <span class="inc">inc</span>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="alterDOM">Alter DOM</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```